# Does anyone know how to use Expression in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I'm making a calculator in Android Studio and am facing a problem.

**Here is my code:**

```
String input = getinput();
try {
   if (!isEmpty() && !stateError) {
      if (input.contains("x")){
          input.replaceAll("x","*");
      }
      Expression expression = new ExpressionBuilder(input).build();
   }
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

When I type `Expression`, it shows the error:

> "Cannot resolve symbol 'Expression'."

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Just from looking around online, I don't think `Expression` or `ExpressionBuilder` is part of the Android library. If so, then you'll get a "Cannot resolve symbol Expression" error if you haven't found some library that supports it.

Comment: what you want to do with this code ?

Comment: Use this library: [http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I need to use this to calculate my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have found this or not, but there is [this site](https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/) that I found that seems to be the API for `Expression` and `ExpressionBuilder` called exp4j.

If that is in fact the API, then [this is the download link](https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/download.html) for it.

---

Another way to evaluate an equation from a `String` in Java is to use the ScriptEngine interface along with the ScriptEngineManager class. You can use it like the following:

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("javascript");

try {
    String result = engine.eval(stringEquation).toString();
    System.out.println("Result: "+result);
} 
catch (ScriptException se) {
    // Handle error
}
```

- [Java ScriptEngine doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html)
- [Java ScriptEngineManager doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html)